# Codeigniter 3 once the session ends, the user cannot log back in

Tags: php, mysql, session, codeigniter-3

So in my codeigniter 3 app i prevent user to have multiple login in different browser or device. When the user is logged in and waiting for the session to end, and then the user refreshes the app it will return to the login page, the problem is that the user cannot log back in because it detects the user is already logged in on another device, can anyone help?

table users have session_id column

login controller

```
    public function auth_login()
        {
            $this->load->model('M_Auth');
            $this->load->library('form_validation');
    
            $rules = $this->M_Auth->rules();
            $this->form_validation->set_rules($rules);
    
            if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
                return $this->load->view('auth-login');
            }
    
            $email = $this->input->post('email');
            $password = $this->input->post('password');
    
            // Check if the user is already logged in on another browser or device
            
            $user_session_id = $this->M_Auth->get_user_session_id($email);
            if ($user_session_id && $user_session_id != session_id()) {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('message_login_error', 'Your account is already logged in on another browser or device.');
                return $this->load->view('auth-login');
            }
    
            if ($this->M_Auth->login($email, $password)) {
                redirect('user_home');
            } else {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('message_login_error', 'Login Gagal, pastikan email dan password benar!');
            }
    
            redirect('login');
        }
```

check login status

```
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->model('M_Auth');
    
        if (!$this->M_Auth->check_login_status()) {
            redirect('login');
        }

    }
```

M_Auth model

```
private $_table = "users";

  public function login($email, $password)
    {
        $this->db->where(['email' => $email, 'level' => 'Admin']);

        $query = $this->db->get($this->_table);
        $user = $query->row();
        if (!$user) {
            return FALSE;
        }
        if (!password_verify($password, $user->password)) {
            return FALSE;
        }

        // Store the session ID in the database for this user
        $data = [
            'session_id' => session_id(),
        ];
        $this->db->where('id', $user->id);
        $this->db->update($this->_table, $data);

        $data = array(
            "user_id" => $user->id,
            'email' => $user->email,
            'logged_in' => true
        );

        $this->session->set_userdata($data);
        $this->_update_last_login($user->id);

        return $this->session->has_userdata('user_id');
    }

    public function get_user_session_id($email)
    {
        $this->db->where('email', $email);
        $query = $this->db->get($this->_table);
        $user = $query->row();
        return $user ? $user->session_id : NULL;
    }


    private function _update_last_login($id)
    {
        $data = [
            'last_login' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
        ];

        return $this->db->update($this->_table, $data, ['id' => $id]);
    }

    public function check_login_status()
    {
        $user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
        
        if (!$user_id) {
            return FALSE;
        }
        
        $user = $this->db->get_where($this->_table, ['id' => $user_id])->row();
        
        if (!$user) {
            return FALSE;
        }
        
        return TRUE;
    }
```

session config

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database'; 
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session'; 
$config['sess_expiration'] = 3600;
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions'; 
$config['sess_match_ip'] = false; 
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
```

Comment: Not sure where in the code you have shown that restriction to one device/browser is actually happening; but in any case, you will likely have to work with some sort of timeout, so that sessions that do not _explicitly_ get ended via a logout, will be considered as "expired" after a certain time of inactivity.

Comment: can you post your logout function !!